# iPhone GLSL dynamic branching issue

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, glsl, shader

I am trying to pass an array of vec3 as uniform and then iterate through them on each pixel. The size of array varies on situations so I can't make the loop with constant number of iterations.

Here is the code:

```
precision highp float;
precision highp int;

varying vec4 v_fragmentColor;

varying vec4 v_pos;

uniform int u_numberOfParticles;

const int numberOfAccumsToCapture = 3;
const float threshold = 0.15;              
const float gooCoeff = 1.19;

uniform mat4 u_MVPMatrix;
uniform vec3 u_waterVertices[100];

void main()
{
    vec4 finalColor = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);

    vec2 currPos = v_pos.xy;

    float accum = 0.0;
    vec3 normal = vec3(0, 0, 0);

    for ( int i = 0; i < u_numberOfParticles; ++i )
    {
        vec2 dir2 = u_waterVertices[i].xy - currPos.xy;
        vec3 dir3 = vec3(dir2, 0.1);
        float q = dot(dir2, dir2);

        accum += u_waterVertices[i].z / q;
    }

    float normalizeToEdge = 1.0 - (accum - threshold) / 2.0;

    if (normalizeToEdge < 0.4)
        finalColor = vec4( 0.1, normalizeToEdge + 0.5, 0.9-normalizeToEdge*0.4, 1.0);

    if ( normalizeToEdge < 0.2 )
    {
        finalColor = vec4( 120.0/255.0, 245.0/255.0, 245.0/255.0, 1.0);
        float shade = mix( 0.7, 1.0, normal.x);
        finalColor *= shade;
    }

    gl_FragColor = vec4(finalColor);
}
```

The problem is here:

```
for ( int i = 0; i < u_numberOfParticles; ++i )
{
    vec2 dir2 = u_waterVertices[i].xy - currPos.xy;
    vec3 dir3 = vec3(dir2, 0.1);
    float q = dot(dir2, dir2);

    accum += u_waterVertices[i].z / q;
}
```

When I make the for-loop like this

```
for ( int i = 0; i < 2; ++i )
{
    //...
}
```

I get double the framerate even though u_numberOfParticles is also 2

Making it like this

```
for ( int i = 0; i < 100; ++i )
{
    if (i == u_numberOfParticles)
        break;
    //...
}
```

gives no improvement.

The only way I know to cope with this situation is to create multiple shaders. But The size of array may vary from 1 to 40 and making 40 different shaders just because of the for-loop is stupid. Any help or ideas how to deal with this situation ?

Comment: How often does the u_numberOfParticles change? Can you set it once during the runtime?

Comment: @Kimi, it changes when I add new particles, so pretty often.. It can be like 15, then 20, then 30, then again 15, I can set it always to be 40 e.g. but that's inefficient.

Comment: The reason why you are getting better results when setting the number of iterations to a small constant is because of compiler loop unrolling and constant array index. Loop can not be unrolled if you have a dynamic break clause. Are you running the supplied code within the fragment shader (gl_FragClolor)? If yes, it would be more efficient to compute the values within the vertex shader and pass accum as a varying.

Comment: @Kimi, Yes this is a fragment shader. I am rendering a full screen quad so I can't calculate values on vertecies. I think that there are solutions of how to implement this behaviour on shaders but more efficiently..

I could leave actually the constant = 40, but then in case of 10 particles, it will make 30 iterations more.. and that's a serious impact on performance.

Comment: Also I would suggest testing on real devices and ignoring whatever performance you get in the simulator.  The sim is very irrelevant for frame rates.  It can be faster or slower.  And even between two different generation of devices you'll see much difference performance.  The iPhone 5 is MUCH faster than the 4 or even the 4S.

Comment: I didn't dissect all your code, but you also might be better off doing some of this calculation in c++ instead of in the shader.  Open ended loops in shaders is a bad idea in practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with @badweasel that you're approach is not really suited for shaders.

From what I understand you are calculating the distance from the current pixel to each particle, sum something up and determine the color using the result.

Maybe you could instead render a point sprite for each particle and determine the color by smart blending.

You can set the size of the point sprite in the vertex shader using `gl_PointSize`. In the fragment shader you can determine the location of the current pixel within the point sprite by using `gl_PointCoord.xy` (which is in texture coordinates, i.e. [0..1]). By knowing the size of your point sprite you can then calculate the distance of the current pixel from the particles center and set the color to something. By additionally enabling blending you may be able to achieve the summing you do inside your loop, but with much higher frame rates.

Here are vertex and fragment shader I use for rendering "fake" spheres via point sprites as an example on how to use point sprites.

VS:

```
#version 150
in vec3 InPosition;

uniform mat4 ModelViewProjectionMatrix;
uniform int Radius = 10;

void main()
{
    vec4 Vertex = vec4(InPosition, 1.0);
    gl_Position = ModelViewProjectionMatrix * Vertex;
    gl_PointSize = Radius;
}
```

FS:

```
#version 150
out vec4 FragColor;

void main()
{
    // calculate normal, i.e. vector pointing from point sprite center to current fragment
    vec3 normal;
    normal.xy = gl_PointCoord * 2 - vec2(1);
    float r2 = dot(normal.xy, normal.xy);
    // skip pixels outside the sphere
    if (r2 > 1) discard;
    // set "fake" z normal to simulate spheres
    normal.z = sqrt(1 - r2);
    // visualize per pixel eye-space normal
    FragColor = vec4(gl_PointCoord, normal.z, 1.0);
}
```

Note, that you need to enable: `GL_POINT_SPRITE`, `GL_PROGRAM_POINT_SIZE` for using point sprites.

Comment: Right now I use the approach like you suggested. I have some "special" textures rendered and then after blending, I analyze the alpha value on each pixel and decide what that pixel should look like. This appears to be much much faster because of removing those loops in fragment shader. Still, thank you.